# Как в ASP.NET MVC сделать всплывающую форму?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Например, пользователь нажимает на кнопку и вместо перехода на новую страницу, появляется всплывающее окно с этой формой..

Answer (score 5):

Это называется "модальные окна":

```js
// при клике на оверлей либо на кнопку убираем класс .shown со всех модальных окон и оверлея
$('.overlay, .modal-close').click(function() {
  $('.modal, .overlay').removeClass('shown');
});

// при клике на кнопку открытия модального окна получаем его id и докидываем класс .shown к нему и оверлею 
$('.open-modal').click(function() {
  let modalId = $(this).data('modal-id');
  $('.overlay, #' + modalId).addClass('shown');
});
```

```css
.modal {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -150px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 5;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.modal .modal-close {
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  stroke: black;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 3;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  display: none;
}

.modal.shown,
.overlay.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-modal-id="modal-1" class="open-modal">Open modal #1</button>
<button data-modal-id="modal-2" class="open-modal">Open modal #2</button>

<div id="modal-1" class="modal">
  <span class="modal-close">
  <svg viewbox="0 0 40 40">
    <path class="close-x" d="M 10,10 L 30,30 M 30,10 L 10,30" />
  </svg>
  </span>
  <div>
    Modal 1
  </div>
</div>
<div id="modal-2" class="modal">
  <span class="modal-close">
  <svg viewbox="0 0 40 40">
    <path class="close-x" d="M 10,10 L 30,30 M 30,10 L 10,30" />
  </svg>
  </span>
  <div>
    Modal 2
  </div>
</div>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Варьировать с данными для окна можно как угодно:

```js
$('.overlay, .modal-close').click(function() {
  $('.modal, .overlay').removeClass('shown');
});

$('.load-modal-frame').click(function() {
  let url = $(this).attr('href');
  $('.modal iframe').attr('src', url);
  $('.overlay, .modal').addClass('shown');
  
  return false;
});
```

```css
.modal {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  z-index: 5;
  padding-top: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal .modal-close {
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  stroke: black;
}

.modal iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-width: 0;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 3;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  display: none;
}

.modal.shown,
.overlay.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/" class="load-modal-frame">Open StackOverflow</a>
<br>
<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/690722/235242/" class="load-modal-frame">Open my question</a>

<div class="modal">
  <span class="modal-close">
  <svg viewbox="0 0 40 40">
    <path class="close-x" d="M 10,10 L 30,30 M 30,10 L 10,30" />
  </svg>
  </span>
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```